# Is it possible to turn off cap fill on an existing cylinder?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I made a beer bottle with inner walls and everything by modifying a cylinder, but I didn't realize that Blender automatically fills them. Is there a way of turning this off or a better way to model a bottle?

Comment: When you create a cylinder you can choose to fill with an n-gon, triangles or nothing. Once the cylinder has been modified you will have to delete the faces manually.

Comment: They are only two faces which you have to delete, which takes about 4 seconds. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have to delete the faces manually. You can change it directly after adding, though.